# How to keep the aspect ratio of an image when increasing the size using Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm loading an image from external sources. I'd like to increase the size of the image without it stretching. I've tried using different Content Scales and the Aspect Ratio modifier to achieve this, but nothing seems to work. This is my current implementation.

```
 Image(
       painter = rememberImagePainter(imageUrl),
       contentDescription = "",
       contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
       modifier = Modifier
            .size(156.dp)
            .aspectRatio(1f)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)))
```

Comment: Please show how you do it wrong.

Comment: `contentScale = ContentScale.Crop`

Comment: I tried that, but it cuts part of the top and bottom of the image.